# Android Rest POST not working

Tags: android, json, post, webclient

So I have a webclient running. The webclient creates JSON files which I can use in my android using a simple URL. GET is working perfectly, but now I am struggeling with the POST.

My code

Login method in webclient:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes =  "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
User serviceLogin(@RequestBody User u) {
    if (userService.login(u) > -1) {
        return userService.findUser(u.getUsername());
    } else {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

ServerCaller:

```
public ServerError login(String username, String password) {
       User user = new User();
       user.setUsername(username);
       user.setPassword(password);

       try {
           String URL = "http://"+ipAddress+"/ProjectTeamF-1.0/service/login.json";
           Object[] params = new Object[]{URL,user};
           receivedUser = new login().execute(params).get();

       } catch (ResourceAccessException rae) {
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.ServerNotFound;
       } catch (HttpServerErrorException hsee) {
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.WrongData;
       } catch(RestClientException rce){
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.WrongData;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("error " + e);
           receivedUser = null;
           return ServerError.OtherError;
       }
       return ServerError.NoError;
   }
```

View:

```
private void instantiateElements() {
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    main = (Button) findViewById((R.id.main));

    serverCaller = ServerCaller.getInstance();

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

            serverCaller.login(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),serverCaller.getReceivedUser().getUserID(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }
    });
}
```

Async method:

```
public class login extends AsyncTask<Object[],Integer,User> {

@Override
protected User doInBackground(Object[]... params) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> list = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    list.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(list);
    User user = new User();
    String url = "http://192.168.137.1:8080/ProjectTeamF-1.0/service/login.json";
    HttpEntity<User> entity = new HttpEntity<User>(user);

    ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,entity,User.class);
    User u = response.getBody();

    return u;

}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
03-06 11:33:02.630: ERROR/power(176): *** set_screen_state 1
03-06 11:33:02.670: ERROR/Launcher(723): setWindowOpaque()
03-06 11:33:02.750: ERROR/Launcher(723): MTP-LAUNCHER: media scanning not yet finished.
03-06 11:33:05.130: ERROR/UinboxLogger(3355): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >> Context   is android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@405249f8
03-06 11:33:06.880: ERROR/Launcher(723): setWindowOpaque()
03-06 11:33:09.910: ERROR/Launcher(723): setWindowOpaque()
03-06 11:33:09.930: ERROR/Launcher(723): MTP-LAUNCHER: media scanning not yet finished.
03-06 11:33:10.000: ERROR/Launcher(723): setWindowOpaque()
03-06 11:33:23.540: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at teamf.view.Login$2.onClick(Login.java:61)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 11:33:23.550: ERROR/(176): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

I get a NullpointerException from the Toast in my view.

Andy ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the use of creating an asynctask if you call get on it ? (you'll have networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: We are using a postForEntity in an asynctask because we read somewhere that you couldn't use rest calls in the main thread.

Comment: yes, but by calling get(), you are effectively anihilating the benefit of the asynctask

Comment: @BartLeemans get() on async task blocks your UI thread as njzk2, and Have you tried my answer..

Comment: @Pragnani tried your answer but still got a NPE

Comment: @njzk2 How should I get working then? I am out of ideas..

Comment: start by post your stacktrace ...

Comment: then, what's line 61 ?

Comment: Like I said, it refers to the Toast in my view: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),serverCaller.getReceivedUser().getUserID(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: It is not the toast where de program crashes, put since the postforEntity doesn't work correctly the current receivedUser is null en therefor it is not able to get it's userId. That is why it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your toast in the onPostExecute of your asynctask. Then it will fire after the task is done. Now you call get immediately and your request is not done yet, the doInBackground of your asynktask is still busy.